# Entity Framework Core 2.1 - Getting StackOverflowException when executing queries with many columns

Tags: iis, entity-framework-core, stack-overflow, entity-framework-core-2.1

Since updating to Entity Framework Core 2.1 (currently on 2.1.1), I have run into a number of queries that now throw a StackOverflowException. These queries worked in v2.0.x. It is only on larger queries - 50+ columns. Most of the queries aren't complex - they are all a single select statement with 10-15 joins and a filter or 2.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll

This is all I get. I am unable to get any stack trace or other helpful information.

I have a DebugLoggerProvider set up on the DbContext and it appears that the query is compiled and executed just fine:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command: Information: Executed DbCommand (162ms) [Parameters=[@__Id_0='1'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']

Is there some issue materializing? The object I'm projecting into has no self-references, just simple properties. I can run the exact same query perfectly fine in LINQPad. I only see the StackOverflowException when running in my ASP.NET MVC (not Core) website.

I can comment out a chunk of property projections and get the query to work, but which properties does not seem to matter. It's as if there is some column limit, yet it works fine in LINQPad and worked fine before.

Any ideas on what is happening or even how I could get more information?

Comment: How are the queries generated and/or how are the columns used? Chaining conditions or select clause (I suspect the former)? StackOverflow is also affected by Thread Stack size. Is this different under ASP.NET than the default 1MB (that I assume LINQPad uses)? Could test that by using a smaller stack with `new Thread(.., stack)` in LINQPad, to see if it can repro there under "selected" situations.

Comment: That looks like it would solve the issue! I tried a new Thread in LINQPad with ~256KB stack size and it bombed. Changing to around 1MB worked. So what is the best solution to fix this for my website? Is it reasonable to change the stack size for my website? If so, how should I do that (a configuration setting would be ideal). Or is there something I can tweak with the query? The way the columns are used is very simple - they are straight table values (SELECT [Table].[ColumnName] AS MyValue...). No coditions or anything complex.

Comment: Not sure if it's a 'solution', was mainly trying to narrow down the repro case :D That's *a lot* of stack whumpaloo going on. This might be relevant, at least wrt the breakpoints see https://serverfault.com/a/776381/388772 (says 'modern' IIS/workers is 256k by default); I'd be hesitant to recommend editbin or otherwise mucking with binaries, especially since this is a "new" issue :}